# Устройство библиотек C++

Tags: c++, библиотеки

Здравствуйте меня интересует устройство работы библиотек, именно: для чего используются *.DLL файлы библиотек и как они свзяаны с* .lib файлами, которые кладутся в папку lib компилятора, с файлами *.h ,которые кладутся в сам проект, почему нельзя просто добавить .h файл в проект? 
Прошу мне объянснить, т.к сам в этом не разбираюсь, извините, если вопрос поставлен глупо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Начнем с основ:) Первоначально компилятор превращает исходный файл в промежуточный формат .obj (т.н. объектный файл), в нем нет ничего кроме машинного кода программы и ссылок на внешние функции библиотек (ссылки получаются из файлов заголовков). В файлах заголовков как правило нет кода, там только объявления ("загловки") процедур и функций. Далее, чтобы превратить объектный файл в исполняемый, его нужно скормить линковщику, но также линковщику нужны еще и файлы .lib, в которых находятся уже скомпилированные функции, на которые есть ссылки в объектном файле. Линковщик все это хозяйство соединяет, и получается готовый исполняемый файл, в котором есть и код программы, и код вызываемых функций.

Файлы lib называются статическими библиотеками, т.к. их можно присоединить к программе только во время компиляции. Также, существуют динамические (динамически подключаемые) библиотеки (dinamiс-link libraries, dll), в отличие от статических библиотек, они подключаются либо в момент запуска программы, либо уже после ее запуска. Для того чтобы подключить dll в момент запуска, к программе должна быть прилинкована статическая библиотека lib, в которой есть ссылки на функции библиотеки dll. В сам исполняемый файл добавляются только эти ссылки на функции, но не сами функции из dll.

Comment: Ну маленькое добавление. В объектных файлах ещё присутствует информация, необходимая для перенастройки адресов (таблицы переместимости), для перевычисления адресных констант в зависимости от того, какое место займёт код. В общем случае, после линковки программа и/или dll должна быть загружена по строго определённому адресу. Есть средства этого избежать. Такой код называются позиционно-независимым (PIC -- position independent code). В linux все dll имеют признак PIC (В виндах -- нет)

Comment: В dll для этих целей используется таблица релокаций.

Comment: Ага, и некоторые (например разработчики cygwin'а) уже сталкивались с тем, что в процессе работы системе приходится перемещать dll на новые адреса (когда одновременно используются библиотеки, занимающие одни и те же адреса)

Comment: То есть, если у меня есть DLL и LIB стороннего производителя, есть три пути!? - 1) Использовать LIB на этапи компилляции, при которые функции библиотеки присоеденятся к коду проекта!? 2) Использовать DLL функции которой будуд вызываться динамически в момент работы программы!? 3) Использовать одновременно LIB и DLL для загрузки библиотеки при загрузки моего приложения!?

Comment: Обычно те lib, которые идут с  dll, нужны именно для линковки dll, а самих функций в них нет. В glut сделано именно так. Поэтому пути только два: линковать lib, чтобы получить доступ к функциям dll, или линковать функции dll [явно, во время работы программы](http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/winapi/r.php?41).

Comment: @alexlz, я сталкивался с тем, что плагин к Total Commander из-за отсутствия таблицы релокаций пытался загрузиться по адресам, занятым самим тоталом. Плагин правда потом починили.

Это я к тому, что "правильные" dll, имеющие таблицу релокаций, вполне себе могут загружаться не по фиксированному, а по заданному системой адресу.

Answer (score 6):

.dll - это dynamic-link library (динамически подключаемая библиотека), содержит откомпилированный код предоставляемых библиотекой функций.

.lib  -- это static libraries (статические библиотеки), представляют собой архив набора объектных файлов, каждый из которых является результатом компиляции одного исходного файла (.c, .cpp).

.h файлы обычно содержат только объявления предоставляемых библиотекой функций и констант. Этого достаточно для компиляции кода используюшего библиотечные функции. На выходе компилятора снова получается один или несколько объектных файлов.

Для того, чтобы из объектных файлов получился исполняемый файл, их (объектные файлы) нужно слинковать. В процессе линковки разрешаются обращения к библиотечным функциям либо путем вставки реализации из статических библиотек внутрь исполняемого файла, либо путем добавления ссылок на соотв. реализации в динамических библиотеках.

[Более детальное описание](http://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html)