# Заголовочные файлы в консольном приложении

Tags: c++

Для чего `Visual studio` при создании консольного приложения добавляет такие заголовочные файлы, как `stdio.h` и `tchar.h`?

Comment: а что именно вас интересует? Содержимое файлов? Так открыть их можно. Добавлять их не обязательно, но MS VS любит свои типы данных использовать и функции main.

Comment: @pavel для чего они нужны?

Comment: Предполагается, что функционал этих заголовков будет полезен разработчику в большинстве случаев.

Comment: а для чего вообще нужны заголовочные файлы?

Comment: @vitya345, в них объявлены функции стандартной библиотеки в данном случае. В общем случае - в них обычно выносят объявления глобальных переменных/функций, находящихся в другом модуле. Можно почитать здесь, например: [Устройство библиотек C++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/73230/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA-c/73243#73243)

Comment: В tchar.h находится определение типа `TCHAR` и переопределения имен функций.

Comment: Что и как будет в новосозданном проекте, зависит от выбранного вами шаблона. Если вы выберете шаблон «пустой проект», ничего добавляться не будет, даже функция `main`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

`stdio.h` добавляется, чтобы обеспечить стандартный ввод-вывод в стиле `printf()` / `scanf()`.

`tchar.h` добавляется как универсальный способ (от MS) писать код, независимый от того, будет ли это Unicode-программа или программа с использованием обычных `char` — вы в любом случае пишите все строки в стиле `T("somestring")`, и используете специальные макросы для всех функций, работающих со строками, например, `_tfopen` вместо `fopen`.

Answer (score 0):

В этих заголовочных файлах находятся прототипы функций стандартной библиотеки (а также определения структур, макросы и т. д.). Предназначение конкретных файлов найти несложно: [stdio.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/), [tchar.h](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c426s321.aspx)

Так как эти файлы относятся к стандартной библиотеке C++, при компиляции нет необходимости явно указывать их использование.