# C++ Разница между заголовочным и файлом реализации?

Tags: c++

В чем разница между заголовочным и файлом реализации и какие существуют стандарты оформления C++ кода? Сделав C++ класс (не интерфейс) думаю неудобно открывать/создавать еще один файл и определять все. В чем плюсы такого подхода?

Comment: И хотя я и поставил минус за такой, с позволения сказать вопрос, попытюсь объяснить максимально просто: используйте `h` и `hpp` файлы ТОЛЬКО для объявления функций и классов. А для их определения используйте `c` и `cpp` файлы. И из этого, думаю понятно, что включения с помощью директивы `include` требуют ТОЛЬКО хэдэры (тобишь `h` и `hpp` файлы).

Comment: Это вполне нормальный вопрос, не за что ставить минус. Многие были новичками и не все внимательно читали книги. Напишите нормальный ответ - и уверен: ещё долго время будете собирать плюсы на такой ответ. И плюса вопрос недостоин, вот ответ если появится - то да.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Устройство библиотек C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/73230/%d0%a3%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba-c)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, это не всегда так, например `minizip` подключается `.с` файлом через инклюде, и таких примеров полно. Но сама идеология верна, хоть на практике 
и встречаютсяя различные варианты.

Comment: @A K [Многие были новичками] Я бы сказал даже больше, ВСЕ когда-то были новичками. Еще ни разу не было такого, чтобы человек родился сразу со знанием языка С++. :-)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, и тем не менее существует немало "библиотек", реализованных даже в одном .h файле. Я уже не говорю о всех библиотеках, использующих templates, где значительная часть рабочего кода классов и функций просто обязана быть в .h Так что, лучше отзовите свой минус

Answer (score 9):

В С / C++ текст программы разделяется на множество клочков, каждый из которых хранится в отдельном текстовом файле. На первом этапе сборки препроцессор начинает читать это отдельные файлы заменяя директивы `#include` на содержимое соответствующих текстовых файлов и получая на выходе длинный текстовый документ единицы трансляции, который затем передается компилятору.

Те текстовые файлы, которые включаются в другие текстовые файлы при помощи директивы `#include` обычно называют заголовочными файлами и используют для них расширения `.h` `.hpp` `.hxx` `.inl` и подобные (многие заголовочные файлы из стандарной библиотеки вообще не имеют расширения). А те текстовые файлы, с которых начинается построение единицы трансляции (соответственно эти файлы обычно передаются среди аргументов командной строки компилятору) обычно имеют расширение `.c` `.cpp` `.cc` или `.cxx`.

Заголовочные файлы с расширением `.inl` обычно отличаются от других заголовочных файлов тем, что они не содержат [include guard](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) и их содержимое может многократно встречаться в тексте единицы трансляции.

Answer (score 6):

Как тут уже правильно сказали, разница в этих файлах весьма условная. Исторически в языке Си в .h файлах хранились декларации, а в .c файлах хранились реализации.

Декларации это то, что используется в более чем одном месте программы. Исторически в языке Си это были дефайны, прототипы функций, описания структур, декларации typedef.

Реализации это то, что должно быть только в одном месте программы. Исторически в языке Си это были реализации функций и статические данные.

В языке С++ это деление сохранилось с учетом того, что в .h файлах теперь содержатся описания классов, шаблонов, констант и опять же всего того, что используется в более чем одном месте программы.

Также с появлением шаблонов в языке С++ наметилась тенденция (особенно в построении библиотек шаблонов), что вся программа содержится в .h файлах.

UPD1:

Так как в .h файлах хранятся декларации (то есть информация, которая должна использоваться в разных единицах трансляции), то предусмотрен механизм #include. С помощью механизма #include можно (и нужно) включать файлы с декларациями в разные единицы трансляции, там, где нужна информация о пользовательских структурах данных, прототипах функций и типах (а в С++ еще и о шаблонах, константах и прочих нововведениях).

Вообще весь язык Си был сделан Ричи и Томсоном "для себя", как инструмент при написании первых версий Юникса. Поэтому этот язык содержит так много элементов, которые поддерживают разработку программ при помощи транслятора с языка высокого уровня. Разделение программы на .h и .c/.cpp файлы как раз и относится к такой поддержке и это разделение вытекает из логики деления проекта на разные единицы трансляции то есть на разные файлы.