# Работа заголовочных файлов

Tags: c++

Возможно вопрос покажется глупым, но я новичок в работе с С++.

Как заголовочный файл знает где брать extern данные/функцию, определение класса... Например у нас есть заголовочный MyClass.h с объявлением класса, а также уйма .cpp файлов с

#include "MyClass.h"

Как он ищет нужный ему файл с определением методов класса?

Comment: `#include "MyClass.h"` - .h файл вставляется в .h или .cpp файл. .h файл не ищет определение, определение ищет линковщик.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work

Comment: А ему ничего знать не надо. все что делает include это при компиляции вместо этой строки вставляет сам текст файла. после чего компилятор уже имеет дело с большим текстом, включающим в себя все, что было в различных include.

Comment: Честно говоря да, вопрос действительно не ахти. Вам стоит почитать про стадии компиляции, единицы трансляции и линковку в С++. Также по теме: [C++ Разница между зголовочным и файлом реализации?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/876163/c-Разница-между-зголовочным-и-файлом-реализации/876207#876207)

Answer (score 1):

Задача заголовочного файла - обеспечить самостоятельную *компилируемость* единицы трансляции, включающей этот заголовочный файл. Для этого в заголовочном файле должны присутствовать в первую очередь *объявления* разнообразных идентификаторов. Никаких "определения методов класса" или "extern данных" для этого не нужно. Поэтому никаким поиском определений заголовочный файл не занимается.

Некоторые *определения* в общем случае могут быть нужны для успешной компиляции единицы трансляции. Это определения типов, определения шаблонов, определения `inline` сущностей или сущностей с внутренним связыванием (константы, например) и пр. Такие определения будут помещаться напрямую в заголовочный файл, поэтому вопроса "поиска" таких определений не возникает.

Что касается остальных определений, задача заголовочного файла заключается только в том чтобы *пообещать*, что такие определения где-то существуют и описать их внешние свойства (типы переменных, списки параметров функций и т.п.). Больше от заголовочного файла ничего не требуется.

Поиск внешних определений - задача линкера. Линкер будет искать определения среди всех единиц трансляции, участвующих в сборке программы. Предоставить все необходимые данные на вход линкеру - ваша задача. Заголовочные файлы к этому процессу уже не имеют прямого (или никакого) отношения.

Answer (score 1):

Если коротко, допустим есть файлы:

```
main.cpp
List.h
List.cpp
```

**List.h:**

```
#ifndef _LIST_
#define _LIST_
            class List{
        void insert(int a);
    //...
         };
#endif
```

**List.cpp:**

```
#include "List.h"
void List::insert(int a)
{
//...
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
 #include "List.h"

int main()
{
List list;
list.insert(5);
return 0;
}
```

.h - файл для объявления

.cpp - файл для определения

**1 ) Препроцесор**

Обработка макросов, include'ов

**List.cpp:**

```
 class List{
           void insert(int a);
          //...
              };


    void List::insert(int a)
        {
        //...
        }
```

**main.cpp:**

```
class List{
           void insert(int a);
          //...
              };
int main()
    {
    List list;
    list.insert(5);
    return 0;
    }
```

**2) Компиляция**

На каждую единицу трансляции(cpp файл) создается объектный файл. Будет создано:

```
List.obj
main.obj
```

**3)Линковка**

Связывает объектные файлы и библиотеки (ищет определения методов) и создает исполняемый файл

```
program.exe
```