# Как правильно разбивать программу на модули в C++?

Tags: c++, qt

К примеру у меня есть проект на Qt, есть main.cpp, mainform.h mainform.cpp. В mainform.cpp я объявляю какие либо методы по нажатию кнопок и тд.
Как правильно разбивать программу на модули?(h и cpp). Если у меня есть функции сохранения/загрузки файлов, то мне нужно их вынести в отдельный header/cpp под названием FileManagment?
Сам уже запутался, заранее благодарю!

Comment: h и cpp - это не модули, см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/876163/c-%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8/876207#876207 Разбитие программы на заголовочные файлы / файлы реализации и разбитие программы на модули - не одно и то же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такой принцип, называется [Принцип единой ответственности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). Это когда у вас класс выполняет лишь один вид работ. В вашем примере (очень удачном, кстати) это работа с файлом. Чтение/запись - это всё к одному классу. Обработку считанных данных либо подготовка данных для записи - это можно вынести уже в отдельный класс.

Поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь

Answer (score -1):

Вы говорите о косметическом оформлении. В этом плане если функции/классы не будут использоваться многократно, не важно где и как все будет содержаться - можете ничего не разбивать, а можете хоть для каждой функции отдельный файл сделать. 
Однако если к примеру ваши функции чтения/записи занимают длительное время, желательно вынести их в отдельный поток чтобы не замораживать на время обработки основной eventloop (интерфейс будт "висеть" пока работает какая-то функция).
Как вынести в отдельный поток - читайте про QThread. Например тут https://habr.com/ru/post/150274/

Comment: Что? Зачем вы от файлов к multi-thread пришли? Автор не спрашивал про реализацию своей функции чтения/записи! Или у Вас лишних букв много?