# Помогите разобраться с ООП многофайловый + микросервисный проект

Tags: c++

В идеале я бы хотел найти готовый шаблон архитектуры построение многофайлового проекта.

Если быть точнее я не понимаю зачем нужны лишние файлы `.cpp`

Сейчас я делаю один файл `main.cpp` а все остальные это файлы `.h`

Еще я посмотрел видеоуроки и не понимаю зачем создавать второй файла `.cpp`, где один тянет зависимости с `.h` потом выполняет код. После чего человек снова подключает
 зависимости в `main.cpp` где точка входа и повторяет выполнение той же программы.

Кто это придумал, или это прикол такой технологии **ООП**, разве она упрощает программирование?

С другой стороны я подумал что смотрю не те видел и читаю не ту документацию. Наверно есть программисты которые использую это правильно.

Comment: Что вы будете делать с проектом, в котором 30 млн. строк кода? В один файл запихнёте? А вы сами то сможете понимать что там происходит? И как вы свои наработки перетащите в другой проект? Скопируете файл и начнёте неистово удалять ненужный код? А вдруг удалите нужный?

Comment: @ArchDemon нет вы не поняли, я не использую один файл, я просто разделяю их по файлам `.h` и подключаю их друг с другом через include.
Мой проект остается многофайловым.
Я не понимаю зачем разработчики создают два файла один `.h` и с тем же названием `.cpp`

Comment: Далее они разделяют код на два файла и один фиг подключают все повторно к точке входа где main
По сути это не удобно, вся реализация разбита и одна функция может быть в двух файлах одновременно по частям, разве это удобно метаться с одного файла к другому что бы понять как работает код?

Comment: Вам стоит ознакомиться с [C++ Разница между заголовочным и файлом реализации?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/876163/c-%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8/876207#876207) ну и с фазами трансляции заодно. А то смешались в кучу люди, кони... Но плодить .cpp файлы (как то поголовно делают во всех учебниках для начинающих) действительно ни к чему, а то будите часами собирать .

Comment: Если у вас все 30 млн. строк кода в хедерах, и .cpp файл один, то при любом изменении будет пересобираться совершенно весь код.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а вот этого я не знал, спс