# Метод правильного написания кода или устаревший стереотип?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Я как из новой школы программирования не совсем понимаю почему разработчики создают файл `.h` и `.cpp`

На каждый такой файл один делают постоянно одно и тоже, что бы подключать свои написанные функции отдельно.
Но из-за такого метода написания кода в стили псевдо ООП они перестают использовать `template` ведь для него не нужны никакие файлы `.cpp` он с ними не работает. А если они будут использовать `template` вместе со своим стилем `.cpp` получаться просто мясо.

Так вот я понять не могу почему разработчики не переходят на новый стиль программирования с использованием `template` им лень изучать новый стиль или они просто знают какой то секрет.

Даже если посмотреть в библиотеки майкрософт там весь код написан на `template` у них даже нету этих фалов `.cpp`

Вот почему я считаю что использовать `.cpp` это устаревший стиль.

Объясните мне пожалуйста в чем плюсы писать по устаревшему стереотипу?

Comment: *"Даже если посмотреть в библиотеки майкрософт там весь код написан на template у них даже нету этих фалов .cpp"* - покажите мне у них код, скажем, `sqrt`. Или `time`. Или... Да даже обычного `fstream` - докопайтесь до места непосредственной записи в файл. И еще - вы никогда не задумывались, а что у них в этих (похоже, никому не нужных, так ведь?) файлах с расширением `.lib`?...

Comment: @AlexF Примерно как если бы человек на автомобиле спрашивал - ну на хрена ходить пешком? Устаревший стиль, пора ноги ампутировать прямо при рождении...

Comment: А в самой жизни разве все по шаблону?... Если даже это возможно, то такая жизнь вытеснит наши творческие фантазии.  Отдельная компиляция обеспечивает не зависимость , точно также, как и пользователю автомобиля не нужно знать технологию обработки деталей машины, и если вы изменили что то в технологии производства, то это ничем не повлияет на владельца машины  Делает легче читаемость того, что нужно пользователю.

Comment: Что-то у вас все смешалось в кашу. С одной стороны, создавать множество парных файлов .h и .cpp, как это обычно расписывается в учебниках, не нужно и даже вредно. С другой стороны, использование шаблонов ну никаким образом не служит для избавления от никчемных .cpp (единственное исключение - для возможности давать определение статическим переменным прямо в заголовочном файле до С++17) и не должно быть самоцелью. Вот вам [наглядный пример](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/boost/logic/tribool.hpp) - все в заголовочном файле, но никаких template.

Comment: Так какой вывод, давайте итоги подведем. Вариант писать все используя только файлы `.h` и не использовать `.cpp` это хороший стиль программирования на 2020 год?

Comment: если не понимаете, зачем они нужны, то вам [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/876163/c-%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8/876207#876207). А что касается сокращения количества .cpp, то [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319579/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-single-source-project-structures/46321758#46321758)

Comment: Они как раз не компилируют, если код в разных .cpp-файлах - изменяется один .cpp-файл, тогда другой не компилируется. Но если меняется .h-файл, то перекомпилируются все файлы, в которые этот .h включается. Делать надо не так, как велит мода ("стиль"), а так, как удобно.

Comment: @user7860670 кажется начинаю понимать мысль, но не понимаю почему ради скорости быстро компилировать проект, нужно жертвовать удобством читаемости кода и создавать эти повторные .cpp файлы.

Например я сейчас программирую так, создал один файл main.cpp и к нему через include подключаю все нужные мне файлы .h.
само собой самый нижний файл .h имеет контроль над более верхним файлом .h такая архитектура мне кажется очень удобной. Если мне чего то не хватает я могу просто добавить еще один include заранее определив какой нужен ему доступ.
В любом случае каждый файл работает по стилю пирамидки.

Comment: наоборот, ради скорости .cpp как раз не надо плодить

Comment: @Harry так разве я не правильно делаю? У меня `include` файлы все включены в один `.h` а этот в свою очередь включен в `main.cpp` в других файлах `.h` нету никаких подключений `include` они просто по иерархии пирамидки получают доступ от других.
Мне кажется я правильно все делаю.

Comment: он пересобирет не main.cpp, а единицу трансляции, в текст которой попадают все включенные заголовочные файлы.

Comment: "еденицы трансляции заголовочных файлов" не бывает, бывает единица трансляции, сборка которой начинается с .cpp файла и текст которой будет содержать содержимое всех включенных заголовочных файлов (рекурсивно). Перечитайте еще раз, что написано по ранее приведенной мной ссылке...

Comment: Для чего нужны и какие удобства дают cpp файлы причина  далеко не одна. Просто нужно знать, что если есть инструмент, не значит, что его нужно использовать повсеместно, точно также, как в качестве контейнера, не правильно повсеместно использовать только вектор. Да, вопрос хороший, но ответов на него в интернете и в учебниках много, поэтому не думаю, что есть смысл повторяться, написав целую статью с примерами.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110262/discussion-on-question-by-patrik------).