# Как разделить программу?

Tags: c++, методы, include

Есть программа, когда она одна то работает, пробую разделить и оно выдает ошибки [image: LNK2005 и LNK1169]

Мой файл лл.cpp:

```
#include "part.cpp"

//...

int main() {
    //...
}
```

Это файл part.cpp:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include "Header.h"
//определение всех функций
void method_1() {...}
void method_2() {...}
void method_3() {...}
...
void method_10() {...}
```

Я погуглил и обнаружил на английском сайте решение в виде файла-заголовка, но и он тоже не помогает, (Прог-а ниже это этот файл "Header.h"):

```
#pragma once
void method_1();
void method_2();
void method_3();
void method_4();
void method_5();
void method_6();
void method_7();
void method_8();
void method_9();
void method_10();
```

Даже после всего этого при запуске  выдаёт ошибки[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем даже если переставлять #include ошибки не исчезают, а как оно может быть определено если эти методы встречаются только в файле part.cpp, а в лл.cpp они лишь используются я не понимаю. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: `#include "part.cpp"` - ¿Что это делает по-вашему?

Comment: По моему это включает методы из part.cpp в программу.

Comment: Нет, препроцессорная директива include заменяется на весь текст из указанного файла.

Comment: Даже так, как оно может переопределяться если они определяются только в одной программе (part.cpp), а в (лл.cpp) они используются, а ошибки такие же вне зависимости от того есть header.h или нет?

Comment: после того, как `#include "part.cpp"` заменяется на весь текст из part.cpp, этот самый текст part.cpp будет присутствовать в двух файлах как если бы вы взяли и сами скопипастили туда весь part.cpp...

Comment: Вау... Я вас понял, но что с этим делать я без понятия. Вы можете подсказать какие-то пути решения?

Comment: Инклюдить надо заголовочные файлы, `Header.h` в данном случае. И еще вот ликбез https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/876163/c-%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8/876207#876207