# Реализация в хедер .h файле или разделённая на .h и .cpp?

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, какая разница между тем, что я напишу реализацию какого то условного класса или функции в одном хедер файле или разделю их на реализацию в .cpp и прототип в .h ?

Правильно я понимаю, что если мне нет необходимости потом компилировать код в библиотеку, то разницы между этими методами абсолютно нет ?

Comment: Разница в том, что вынос реализации в .cpp создает новую единицу трансляции.

Comment: @user7860670 а хедер с реализацией тогда что? не единица трансляции?

Comment: @ampawd Нет, хедер с реализацией - это по-прежнему хедер.

Comment: @user7860670 Тоесть по содержимому файла компилятор понимает что тут только реализация и создаёт единицу трансляции ?

Comment: @ampawd Ничего такого он не понимает. Единица трансляции соответствует каждому файлу, явно указанному в аргументах командной строки компилятора. см https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/876163/c-%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8/876207#876207

Answer (score 4):

Различия можно раскидать условно на две стопки: различия технологические и человеческий фактор.

Главный технический фактор: **это можно сделать не всегда**. Отделение объявлений от реализации - это важная часть того, как работает компиляция на `C++`. Если у вас есть циклическая зависимость в объявлениях, *вы будете вынуждены* иногда использовать `forward-declaration`, а иногда - полное описание класса. Вот как раз вариант с отдельными файлами для объявления и реализации дает решение этого вопроса - в файле `.h` вы работаете с `forward-declaration`, в файле `.cpp` - с полным объявлением.

(Да, есть [альтернативный вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45402913/how-to-declare-define-interdependent-templates-in-c/45403262) (предложен
@user7860670) при помощи ювелирной расстановки `#include`, но человеческий фактор мешает лично мне рассматривать его всерьез, так это требует от разработчика следования строгим правилам, иначе - матомный взрыв из нетривиальных ошибок в исполнении компилятора).

Также [утверждается](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46321758/5533854), что это катастрофически сокращает время сборки и размер выходного файла, что выглядит перспективно, но достигается ценой головной боли разработчиков.

*Лично на мой взгляд,* размер выходного файла и время сборки - это минорные факторы, а вот тот факт, что разработчик занят выверкой имен и разгребанием ошибок, *вместо решения прикладной задачи* - это главный шоустоппер такого решения. Ферма из тредрипперов под сборку обойдется дешевле времени разработчиков и реабилитации их после нудной работы по приведению хидеров в порядок.

Далее уже всякая лирика:

Технически, тела всего что засунуто в объявление класса, будут расцениваться компилятором как `inline`, следовательно он будет пытаться, по возможности, затолкать эти тела прямо на место, откуда они вызываются - в зависимости от настроек оптимизации, разумеется. Это может повлиять на скорость работы программы и на ее размер, причем в любую сторону.

Тела отдельно стоящих функций же, вы будете вынуждены пометить как `inline`, иначе компилятор работать откажется.

Теперь кратко про человеческий фактор - *это уже вопрос привычки и вкуса.*

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130203/discussion-between-gbg-and-user7860670).

Answer (score 3):

Реализация всего в заголовочных файлах известна как концепция [SCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Compilation_Unit). В качестве преимуществ (для крупных проектов) вы получаете

- Радикальное сокращение времени сборки. Это основная причина для перехода на SCU. Когда у вас есть проект с `n` единицами трансляции, время сборки будет расти ~линейно при добавлении каждой новой единицы трансляции. В то же время при использовании SCU время сборки будет расти только ~логарифмически и добавление новых классов в проект практически никак не будет сказываться на времени сборки.
- Сокращение памяти, требуемой для сборки. Дисковой и оперативной. Хотя одна "большая" единица трансляции будет очевидно занимать куда больше места, чем любая из "маленьких", *общий размер* маленьких единиц трансляции будет куда больше.
- Выигрыш по оптимизации. Очевидно, что все автоматически становится inline.
- Пропадает страх случайно запустить пересборку всего проекта с 0. Это особенно важно в контексте Непрерывной Интеграции, так как это то, чем постоянно занимается CI сервер.
- В коде, в котором задействуется стадия динамической инициализации, исключается проблема Static initialization Order Fiasco, так как порядок инициализации в рамках одной единицы трансляции определен.
- Сокращается риск нарушения One Definition Rule.

В качестве сложностей:

- Разработчики должны четко соблюдать дисциплину организации заголовочных файлов. Header guards, единообразный порядок директив `#include`, обязательное обеспечение самодостаточности каждого заголовочного файла, правильный форвардинг, единство соглашения об именованиях и т.п. Проблема в том, что инструментов для соблюдения этого всего нет, а отход от установленных правил приводит к сообщениям об ошибках, которые еще более мутные, чем обычно.
- Потенциальное увеличение числа файлов в проекте. Смотрите [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45402913/how-to-declare-define-interdependent-templates-in-c/45403262#45403262).
- Больше не получится [сражаться на мечах, отмазываясь, что код компилируется](https://xkcd.com/303/).

некоторые числа:

- время полной сборки упало с ~14 минут до ~20 секунд (1 ядро), размер исполняемого файла сократился в 3 раза (результат преобразования существующего проекта в SCU по моему опыту)
- real-world use cases: [CppCon 2014: Nicolas Fleury "C++ in Huge AAA Games"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYN6eduU06s), [Chromium Jumbo / Unity builds (*"is can save hours for a full build"*)](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/65.0.3283.0/docs/jumbo.md)

Comment: Я правильно понял, что перекомпиляция, скажем, 100 строк из общих 10000 (находятся в 100 файлах) и линкинг 100 файлов требует существенно большего времени, чем компиляция всех 10000 строк и линкинг одного файла? Может у вас там были (*`"время сборки упало с ~14 минут до ~20 секунд"`*) какие-то неучтенные проблемы с make?

Comment: @avp Нет, тут везде идет речь о полной сборке. Инкрементальная сборка примерно сравнима по скорости будет. Однако я вполне допускаю, что в некоторых сценариях за счет долгой линковки инкрементальная сборка запросто может оказаться несколько медленнее.

Comment: Понял. Может все же упомянуть в ответе, 14 сек и 20 мин это полная сборка?

Comment: @avp Упомянул, и еще про одно ядро тоже.