# Ускоряет ли процесс линковки использование ключевого слова static в безымянном пространстве имён?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, компоновщик

Для того, чтобы глобальные переменные/функции имели внутреннее связывание (`internal linkage`), начиная с `C++11` достаточно поместить их определение в безымянное пространство имён (`unnamed namespace`):

```
namespace {
    int foo() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

До C++11 необходимо было указывать ключевое слово `static`:

```
static int foo() {
    return 42;
};
```

Услышал мнение, что с технической точки зрения при объявлении глобальных переменных/функций в безымянных пространствах имён всё равно лучше дописывать ключевое слово `static`, т.к. это ускоряет процесс линковки:

```
namespace {
    static int foo() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Насколько это правда?

Comment: Во-первых, сомнительно, во-вторых — это (время линковки) так важно?!

Comment: поэтому и спрашиваю. А почему не важно?

Comment: Обычно линковка проходит быстро, поэтому об ее ускорении никто не задумывается. А функции при возможности лучше в самом деле делать static, это повышает инкапсуляцию, сразу говорит читателю кода, что данная функция имеет смысл только в этом файле (единице компиляции)

Comment: @avp повышает инкапсуляцию тут в смысле повышения читабельности кода, не более?

Comment: @magrif, все эти ООП-шные штучки нужны тоолько для улучшения пониманя кода **человеком** (железу, которое реально работает, они до лампочки...)

Comment: @avp *"Обычно линковка проходит быстро, поэтому об ее ускорении никто не задумывается."* С другой стороны, развелось много линковщиков, каждый из которых рекламируется как более быстрый, чем предыдущий: LD, Gold, LLD, Mold... И плюс майкрософтовский link.exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С точки зрения редактора связей (линкера) anon. namespace и static абсолютно эквивалентны (с точностью до манглирования имён):

```
$ cat tmp1.cc
namespace { void foo() {} }
$ g++ -c tmp1.cc && readelf -sW tmp1.o | g foo
     5: 0000000000000000    11 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_13fooEv
$ cat tmp2.cc
static void foo() {}
$ g++ -c tmp2.cc && readelf -sW tmp2.o | g foo
     5: 0000000000000000    11 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 _ZL3foov
$ cat tmp3.cc
namespace { static void foo() {} }
$ g++ -c tmp3.cc && readelf -sW tmp3.o | g foo
     5: 0000000000000000    11 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_1L3fooEv
```

Как можно видеть компилятор использовал символы одинакового типа (`LOCAL DEFAULT`) в порождённых объектных файлах, а значит редактор связей в процессе линковки будет обрабатывать их одинаковым образом (и соответственно время работы не поменяется).

Comment: Не ответ на вопрос. Это результат, а интересует есть ли разница во времени получения этого результата для представленных вариантов.

Comment: @magrif это не результат, а скорее промежуточная стадия. Я дописал вывод (видимо из-за профдеформации мне он изначально показался очевидным).

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, с точки зрения компилятора функция в анонимном пространстве имен вовсе не эквивалентна такой же функции, но с модификатором `static`, как то утверждается в другом ответе. Основное отличие - функция в анонимном пространстве имен не учитывается при выполнении ADL. Так что после простой замены `static` на анонимное пространство имен код может изменить поведение или даже вообще перестать работать, так что тут надо быть аккуратным.

Во-вторых, какай вариант быстрее по скорости последующей линковки - на самом деле не так уж важно, так вклад этих сущностей в общее время линковки не может быть существенным, если только вся программа не состоит из тысяч статических функций и глобальных переменных.

В-третьих, для того чтобы реально ускорить процесс линковки необходимо сокращать число единиц трансляций. В идеале перейти на [сборку SCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Compilation_Unit), где всё реализовано в заголовочных файлах. А вот тут нагромождения глобальных переменных и функций со статическим связыванием могут сыграть с вами злую шутку, так как придется разбираться с коллизиями и избавляться от них.

Comment: "с точки зрения компилятора функция в анонимном пространстве имен вовсе не эквивалентна такой же функции ... Основное отличие - функция в анонимном пространстве имен не учитывается при выполнении ADL" - погодите, вы про статические методы? В вопросе речь явно идёт про статическую _функцию_ (не являющуюся членом класса) и для них это утверждение несправедливо.

Comment: Нет, я про статическую функцию, которая не является членом класса.

Comment: "В идеале перейти на сборку SCU" - вы про Unity Build? Довольно спорное утверждение, т.к. за сокращение времени линковки скорее всего придётся заплатить резким ростом времени компиляции (сравните как вырастает время сборки при включении LTO).

Comment: "Нет, я про статическую функцию" - может тогда приведёте пример/пруфлинк для сомневаюющихся?

Comment: Нет, я не про Unity build. Точнее не совсем про него. И нет, unity и, тем более, полноценное SCU как раз направлено на сокращение времени сборки. см https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1334642/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%85%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80-h-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-h-%d0%b8-cpp/1334666#1334666

Comment: "какой вариант быстрее по скорости последующей линковки - на самом деле не так уж важно, так вклад этих сущностей в общее время линковки не может быть существенны" - для рантайм-линковки он достаточно существенен, чтобы имело смысл разрабатывать специальный тул для уменьшения релокаций (Prelink) `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Нет, рантайм линковка тут вообще ни при чем. К сущностями со внутренним связыванием и со встраиваемым она же не работает.

Comment: "Нет, я не про Unity build" - может тогда приведёте ссылку? "SCU build" не гуглится...

Comment: "К сущностями со внутренним связыванием и со встраиваемым она же не работает" - конечно, поэтому они очень полезны и их надо использовать даже в Unity builds (ваше утверждение "нагромождения ... функций со статическим связыванием" вроде как утверждает обратное).

Comment: Я же уже привел, и в том ответе даже ссылка на википедию для ликбеза есть.

Comment: "И нет, unity и, тем более, полноценное SCU как раз направлено на сокращение времени сборки." - я нежно люблю unity builds, но это утверждение как мимимум спорно (см. хотя бы [вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_build#Effects), там про OOM и параллелизм). Я как компиляторщик добавлю что многие алгоритмы начинают "взрываться" с ростом объёма входного файла.

Comment: Утверждение про "нагромождения ... функций со статическим связыванием" утверждает, что они эти функции (да и глобальные переменные) создают проблемы при SCU, а не про линковку.

Comment: А SCU вовсе не приводит к какому-то радикальному росту объема входного файла. Как раз наоборот, в целом объем обрабатываемых данных радикально снижается. Это второй пункт в том моем ответе. Кроме того, оно никак не препятствует параллелизму при сборке нескольких проектов за счет.

Comment: "они эти функции создают проблемы при SCU, а не про линковку" - я вас понял, да, это действительно проблема для unity. Мой поинт был в том, что если уж код использует глобальные переменные, то с точки зрения ускорения линковки (как статической, так и динамической) `static` "лучше" обычных глобалов.

Comment: "в целом объем обрабатываемых данных радикально снижается" - не совсем так, на этапе мидленда сильно вырастают обрабатываемые структуры данных типа call graph, вырастают размеры функций за счёт более агрессивного межмодульного инлайнинга и клонирования. Добавьте к этому сверхлинейное время работы многих оптимизационных алгоритмов в компиляторе и получите простой способ получить экспоненциальный рост. В частности поэтому для unity-сборок и применятют шардинг.