C++ - Как сделать так чтобы сурс файл читал подключённые библиотеки с файла "main.cpp"?
В файле main.cpp подключён заголовочный файл GLFW/glfw3.h. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы к этому заголовочному файлу имел доступ другой сурс файл, читая её с файла main.cpp.
Вот например у меня есть 3 файла main.cpp, source.hpp и source.cpp, source.hpp подключена к source.cpp. В файле main.cpp подключён заголовочный файл GLFW/glfw3.h в то время как в файле source.cpp он не подключён, но Я хочу сделать так, чтобы файл source.cpp читал заголовочный файл GLFW/glfw3.h с файла main.cpp.
Пример main.cpp:
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "source.hpp"

...

Вот например в этом примере source.hpp не читает GLFW/glfw3.h с main.cpp.
Как сделать так, чтобы файл source.cpp читал заголовочный файл GLFW/glfw3.h не подключая её в самом source.cpp и вообще возможно ли такое в C++?

Один вопрос — зачем?!...

GLFW/glfw3.h - это не библиотека, а заголовочный файл. Каждый файл должен включать все заголовочные файлы, символы из которых он использует. Почитайте про порядок сборки исходного кода С++. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/876163#876207

@Harry это нужно мне для графической библиотеки. Написал функцию для инициализации Windows API, например такую как GLFW.

Смотрите, вы хотите, чтобы все из файла было включено, без включения самого файла в один конкретный файл .cpp. Но при этом все равно хотите его включать - но в другой .cpp. И что это вам дает? Вы не отказываетесь от включения вообще (скажем, для уменьшения зависимостей; для этого имело бы смысл писать свою оболочку вокруг библиотеки) — тогда в чем смысл? Ваш ответ про инициализацию мне непонятен. Как-то раскройте его. Не XY ли у вас проблема?

@Harry что непонятного? Я хочу чтобы один конкретный source source.cpp файл имел доступ к подключённым заголовочным файлам, source файла main.cpp, которые отсутствуют в самом source файле source.cpp и в его заголовочном файле source.hpp но при этом заголовочный файл source.hpp подключён в source файле main.cpp после подключения заголовочного файла GLFW/glfw3.hpp.

А вы не думали, что проще всего включить GLFW/glfw3.hpp в начало заголовочного файла source.hpp, а в main (и другие .cpp) включать уже только source.hpp?

@avp такой вариант меня не устраивает, поскольку Я хочу чтобы пользователь при подключении заголовочного файла GLFW/glfw3.h или же другого Windows API, например такого как SDL или SFML, в source файле main.cpp, чтобы source файл source.cpp сам определил какой Windows API будет использоваться в source файле main.cpp с помощью директивы #ifdef, иначе нужно будет подключить заголовочные файлы всех Windows API в source файле source.cpp, GLFW, SDL, SFML и т.д.

Другими словами, вы хотите, чтобы при изменении исходного кода (по крайней мере в  части заголовочных файлов) у вас перекомпилировался файл source.cpp с включением нужных заголовочных файлов, исходя из текста main.cpp? Стандартными средствами компилятора такого не сделать. Придется писать свой препроцессор, который надо будет вызывать перед шагом компиляции .cpp файлов

Ну, или как минимум, вам нужен заголовочный файл, который включает описание  используемого API и включается как в source.cpp, так и в другие файлы, использующие функции из source.cpp. При его изменении нужно будет все перекомпилировать

@avp Я хочу чтобы во время компиляции source файла main.cpp, чтобы source файл source.hpp, который подключён после header файла GLFW/glfw3.h в source файле main.cpp прочитал header файл GLFW/glfw3.h с source файла main.cpp однократно во время отсутствия header файла GLFW/glfw3.h в header файле source.hpp и в source файле source.cpp, ключевое слово однократно, нужно это просто для инициализации Windows API.

Не понимю смыла вашего комментария. Для начала, вы понимаете, что 1) стандартный компилятор обрабатывает текст каждого .cpp файла независимо от всех других .cpp файлов. 2) #include это текстовая подстановка, т.е. вместо строки #include GLFW/glfw3.h при компиляции будет вставлен весь текст (с учетом такой же рекурсивной текстовой подстановки) файла GLFW/glfw3.h? Следствием этого будет то, что в рамках компилируемого файла main.cpp текст, вставленный вместо source.hpp будет "видеть"  текст из GLFW/glfw3.h. НО только в этом .cpp файле.

Если у вас какой-то .h файл включается в нескольких разных .h файлах, то для того  чтобы его текст вставлялся один раз независимо от порядка включения всех этих файлов, вам нужно использовать так называемый guard в начале файла. Обычно пишут в первых 2-х строках #ifndef что-то-вроде-имя-этого-файла \n#define  что-то-вроде-имя-этого-файла и #endif в последней строке

Последняя попытка... Вам нужно, чтобы выбор нужной библиотеки делался в единственном месте? тогда это лучше делать в отдельном заголовочном файле, как и сказал @avp. И менять надо будет именно однократно, только не main.cpp, заголовочный файл, добавляя в его начале какой-нибудь #define using_GLFW...

"нужно это просто для инициализации Windows API" Что? Вот про это поподробнее. Так, как вы просите - не делают, и непонятно зачем вам это (из ваших комментариев понятнее не стало).

Не надо в .h и .hpp размещать исполняемый код.
Оберни код инициализации в функцию, которую надо поместить в cpp и вызвать в main.
Ещё файл можно помечать для однократного подключения с помощью (если поддерживается компилятором)
#pragma once

или более традиционно
#ifndef SOME_NAME
  #define SOME_NAME

  // тут остальной код
#endif

