Cмысл .inl файлов в c++?
Наткнулся на такой файл в проекте и решил разобраться, а для чего собственно он нужен.
Стоит сказать, что я сам inline редко использую, плюс сейчас достаточно умные компиляторы, которые сами где нужно могут поставить или проигнорировать inline. Также прочитал, что его еще используют для шаблонов, но четкой структуры и понятия как, зачем и почему нету.
Кто может объяснить, для чего именно он используется и в каких случаях, влияет ли это на производительность, как читает и видит его компилятор?

Можете показать конкретный пример/проект? Четкого соглашения нет (компилятору неважно, какие расширения у заинклуженных файлов), но название звучит так будто туда складывают определения inline функций, чтобы не класть их непосредственно в обычный хедер (а в конце хедера инклудят этот inl).

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/876163/c-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/876207#876207
