# c++ неразрешенный внешний символ D3DXCreateTextureFromFileInMemoryEx

Tags: c++

В официальной документации к функции  D3DXCreateTextureFromFileInMemoryEx написано:
"Требования
ТРЕБОВАНИЯ
Требование  Значение
Заголовок
D3dx9tex. h
Библиотека
D3dx9. lib"
Ну я пишу
#include "D3dx9tex.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"d3dx9.lib")
ошибка: неразрешенный внешний символ D3DXCreateTextureFromFileInMemoryEx
Что делать?????

Comment: .h файл не вклчючает в себя имплементацию, это всего лишь заголовочный файл. [Почитайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/73230/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA-c) на тему библиотек в C++ чтобы лучше понять что это и как их подключать. Эта ошибка значит что файл d3dx9.lib не был найден при линковке.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Если бы lib не был бы найден визуалка бы написала это, она пишет именно неразрешенный символ, значит библиотеку она нашла

Comment: ¿Какая версия Windows SDK и DirectX SDK установлены? И VS.